# Отличие разных комментариев, с++

Tags: c++

Не подскажете в чем функциональное отличие разных видов комментариев в с++ и способы их применения?

```
// 

///

/*  */
```

возможно есть и другие виды комментариев?

Comment: первый однострочный, третий - многострочный

Comment: Многострочный не может вложенность, а однострочный потенциально опасен, если оканчивается `\\`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

С точки зрения *языка*, действительно, только 2  вида комментариев

```
//
```

и

```
/*   */
```

Однако, с т.з. *программиста* есть еще один -- условный оператор макропроцессора -- `#if 0`:

```
#if 0   
  ...  
#endif
```

Хоть он и не является "официальным комментарием", при отладке часто оказывается удобнее остальных.

Во-первых, он позволяет делать **вложенные** "комментарии",
а во-вторых (в сочетании с `#else`) временно комментировать только часть кода и с легкостью переключаться между его вариантами (впрочем, тут уже речь пойдет скорее о *метапрограммировании*).

Comment: Любопытно, что ответ помечен как "лучший", но тем не менее, не содержит описания того, чем отличаются, упомянутые ТС, виды комментариев.

Comment: @alexolut, я просто чуть дополнил остальные ответы..., неявно предполагая, что заинтересованное лицо прочтет их все.

Answer (score 6):

В C++ существуют всего 2 варианта комментариев:

- однострочный `// всё до конца строки является комментарием`
- многострочный `/* всё между является комментарием */`

Варианты, базирующиеся на этих двух, используются для сторонних инструментов. В частности для документирования кода в doxygen `/** */` или в visual studio `///`.

Comment: Кстати, doxygen отлично понимает `///`

Comment: @LXA ну да, а ещё `/*! ... */` и `//!`.

Answer (score 3):

```
//
```

Это простой однострочный комментарий.

```
///
```

Это комментарий для документирования функций, классов, свойств, переменных. Чаще всего используется при построении документации к коду.

```
/*  */
```

Это простой многострочний комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Однострочный комментарий

/* Это многострочный комментарий, 
то есть может состоять из нескольких строк */
```

Более подробно:

- [Tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_comments.htm)
- [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/comment)